Hunting for a particular piece of chess footage
I've been trying to find a particular clip which I remember from a while ago (or the game associated to this clip).
There was some commentary, I think part of a broadcast / commentary associated to another event, where one player (in my memory this was Peter Svidler) had white in the Italian game. The key point is that white actually went wrong early with a bad move order (possibly pushing b4 too early?).
The commentary was highly instructive, explaining clearly why this apparent subtlety was actually very important, and led quickly to a bad position for white.
I've looked up Svidler's games (all the rapid/classical ones that I can find, anyway) and I can't seem to find it at all, which leads me to think that it might not have been him.
This clip is at least a couple of years old, and I thought the discussion was between Svidler and Jan Gustafsson.
Can anyone help me find this? It was long enough ago that I'm reluctant to say that I'm certain about any detail, but what I'm most sure about is that it was a discussion from the perspective of the white side of the Italian game, where white went wrong early and ended up worse quickly, and various subtleties were highlighted. The point being that even the very top players (e.g. Svidler), if they forget their theory, can get into early trouble.

You really need more details. What you have given is not very clear and so there is very little chance of success.

Thanks @Matt. This kind of inability to source a memory can be quite frustrating. If you wish to pursue this, I think your best approach at this point is maybe to email Gustaffson or Svidler
